# Error: Uncaught [TypeError: createKeccakHash is not a function]

Tags: typescript, web3js, ts-jest, react-tsx, testing-library

I am trying to use `web3js` external calls in jest test. Previously i was able to get data, but the error thrown was **can not console response after the end of test**  something like this, although i was able to see the response but in catch block.

But now it is not letting me make any external call.
`HELP`

```
    describe("Deployment", function () {
    it("Should set the right unlockTime", async () => {
        try {
            const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => {return useAccounts()}, { wrapper: MockApp });
            console.log("result BB", result);
            console.log(await result?.current);
            console.log("result A"  , result);
            rerender();

            await waitFor(async () => {
                console.log("hiiiiiiiiiii");
                console.log(await result?.current.bal())
                console.log("bye");
            })

            // const response = await result.current.bal();
            console.log("hiiiiiiiiiii");
            console.log("res-----", result.current);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

[Source file of test] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfIVY.png)

[error] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxj8R.png)

[broken point] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/odVeR.png)